# What is the problem classification (e.g. sequence-to-sequence) for prediction of an autocorrelated sequence from multiple autocorrelated sequences?

Tags: machine-learning, sequence

I will try to provide a simple example to illustrate my question. I have training data for many oil wells. The training data consists of the well identifier, a timestamp, other relevant properties like temperature and pressure and the response variable is oil production rate at the timestamp. I'm trying to predict the oil production rate for a separate set of wells for a period of time given the temperature, pressure, etc. For an individual well, the oil production rate is correlated with the production rate at the timesteps before it. However, between wells there is no relationship between one another. I'm trying to research strategies to improve my predictions for this kind of problem, but I don't really know what to search. It doesn't seem to quite fit as a sequence problem. How would you classify this? I would appreciate any tips for tackling this kind of problem.